# Seeking training plugin for QGIS？

Tags: qgis-plugins, references

I am looking for training app installed inside QGIS, which can be used for training purposes.

I mean, a plugin like an e-learning software than can drives you directly inside the QGIS software and can check your result automatically.

I looked under python plugin repository with `tutorial` or `training` keys but with no good result.

I think it should be better integrate with a C++ plugin or a specific QGIS standalone App than a python plugin, but I could be wrong.

I am also interest about project which use a kind of tutorial module, like step by step, with highlighting zone, mouse move, button action, setting parameters directly under QGIS.

If I am still not clear enough, this kind of app are usual on web, for e.g., when you launch openstreetmap editor on their website, there is a kind of "beginner tutorial". I would know if someone develop something similar under QGIS desktop, never mind if it's on a totally different way.
it´s a kind of state of art about tutorial existing tools under QGIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BoundlessGeo developed a plugin called `Lessons-plugin`.
The description is here: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-lessons-plugin

I saw the demo, it was pretty nice.
There is a video on it: https://av.tib.eu/media/20319

For now, I think you need to install it manually. I tried quickly with the plugin manager (with the BoundlessGeo plugin repository) but it's asking a login/password. You can create an account on their website.

This plugin might be included in QGIS Core following this request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/92